# If the "string" $A \to B$ usually means the type of functions from $A$ to $B$ then what should the string $A\to ?$ mean?

Tags: functions, formal-languages, type-theory, programming

Was thinking of a programming languages in which every string is a valid program.

What is the type of the string `A->?` or `A->` where we used ? not to indicate a type but that any type could go there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little unclear precisely what you're asking, but you can consider $A \to (-)$ to be a [type constructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_constructor) $* \to *$ that takes a type $B$ and maps it to the type $A \to B$. Here $*$ represents the [kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)) of types. This is possible in type theories like [System F$\omega$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F#System_F%CF%89) and programming languages like Haskell.